# Can you convert this Ruby regex to PHP?

Tags: php, ruby, regex

I try to find everything that starts with **((** and ends with **))** but doesn't contain any **!** characters. Here is the regular expression I just generated. (http://rubular.com/r/7rQipcE9FK) But I couldn't figure out how to convert it for PHP preg_match_all.

It also returns **dolor sit amet** as one string but I need ((dolor)) and ((amet)) seperated. Can you help?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Answer (score 4):

You must make the `*` non-greedy, using a `?` after it.

```
/\(\([^!]*?\)\)/
```

code:

```
$text = "((Lorem)) ((!ipsum)) ((dolor)) sit ((amet)), ((!consectetur)) ((!adipisicing)) ((elit))";  
$regex = "/\(\([^!]*?\)\)/";                                                                        

preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);                                                            

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(9) "((Lorem))"
    [1] =>
    string(9) "((dolor))"
    [2] =>
    string(8) "((amet))"
    [3] =>
    string(8) "((elit))"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its almost the same

```
preg_match_all('|\(\([^!]*\)\)|', '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```